# How to load a jQuery script last?

Tags: jquery, headers

How to get this to load last?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("div.domTip_tipBody").mouseover(function(){
   jQuery("#yyy a.tippy_link").css("background-color","yellow");});  

   jQuery("div.domTip_tipBody").mouseout(function(){
   jQuery("#yyy a.tippy_link").css("background-color","red");
 }); 
 });  
 </script>
```

It is running before "div.domTip_tipBody" is being run (which is generated by a shortcode) so nothing happens.

I have tried:

```
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript" defer="defer"></script>
```

in my header.php before

```
</head>
```

but it doesn't help.

Have seen "window.onload =" but not sure how to apply it.

Any insight is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Use wp_footer to put this is the footer area. Read how: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add_action('wp_footer','myscript_in_footer');
function myscript_in_footer(){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery("div.domTip_tipBody").mouseover(function(){
   jQuery("#yyy a.tippy_link").css("background-color","yellow");});  

   jQuery("div.domTip_tipBody").mouseout(function(){
   jQuery("#yyy a.tippy_link").css("background-color","red");
 }); 
 });  
 </script>
<?php
}
```

Comment: Thanks you Rajeev, I tried your code and it to put the js at the bottom, I know have two ways of doing this.  js sill not working for on the output of my shortcode, so it must be a different issue.

Comment: Directly dumping this into footer is _the wrong way_ to do it.

Answer (score 6):

1. Put the code inside a file named `your_name.js`.
2. Add the following to your `functions.php` file:

   ```
   function wpse47618_load_script_last()
   {
       wp_enqueue_script( 'zzz_your_name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'your_name.js', array( 'jquery' ), '0', true );
   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse47618_load_script_last', 99999 );
   ```
3. Check your pages source code if the script was added successfully and if the path to the file is correct. If you use FireBug or other dev tools, click the filename and see it the script content is there.
4. You're done.

Comment: Thank you Kaiser, this put the script at the bottom, for some reason the js is still not reading the selectors out put by the shortcode, it works for everything else though!

Comment: n/p. Note, that this then would be a question for SO. I'd try to simply use the console in your FireBug/Chrome dev bar/IE dev tools, etc. Just write `console.log( jQuery( 'div' ) );` and you'll see if the selection worked.

Comment: Kaiser, I did not know about that functionality, thanks.  When using I see these show up div#domTip_tipBox.domTip_Tip, div#this.tipHeader.domTip_tipHeader, div#this.tipBody.domTip_tipBody

Comment: Iqnore the above.  Kaiser thanks for the response, I did not know about that functionality, thanks.  When using it I see these show up `div#domTip_tipBox.domTip_Tip, div#this.tipHeader.domTip_tipHeader, div#this.tipBody.domTip_tipBody` if I click on them they will take me to css selectors.  I have tried using the "raw" output above and the css selectors they send me to but none of the do my js read.  Is there anything that can be done to help the js read these selectors?

Comment: As I said: That's a Q for SO. But anyway: If you can select them there, then they work. You can also place the `console.log()` directly in your script and see the console output that. That profes, that the script is working. Then it's something else. so: Give it a try and if not -> SO.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a jQuery event delegation issue. If the new DOM elements are added after the page has loaded, jQuery wont read them. So you need to tell jQuery before hand to bind an event if any such element exists now or in future.

try `$.delegate('div.domTip_tipBody','mouseover', function(e){
   jQuery("#yyy a.tippy_link").css("background-color","yellow");});
});`

See http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ , http://lab.distilldesign.com/event-delegation/

Comment: Hello Rashid, thank you for your response I am hopeful that this will solve my problem. I tried this `add_action('wp_footer','myscript_in_footer'); function myscript_in_footer(){ ?>
$.delegate('p','mouseover', function(e){ jQuery("#yyy a.tippy_link").css("background-color","yellow");}); $.delegate('p', function(e){ jQuery("#yyy a.tippy_link").css("background-color","red"); }); });</script>
<?php
}` I change "div.domTip_tipBody" to "p" to check if the function is working, it is not.  Can you see what need to be Changed so that it works?

Comment: Please Read this one instead. Thank you for your response I am hopeful that this will solve my problem. I tried this `add_action('wp_footer','myscript_in_footer'); <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){ ?>
$.delegate('p','mouseover', function(e){ jQuery("#yyy a.tippy_link").css("background-color","yellow");}); $.delegate('p', function(e){ jQuery("#yyy a.tippy_link").css("background-color","red"); }); });</script>
<?php
}` I change "div.domTip_tipBody" to "p" to check if the function is working, it is not.  Can you see what need to be Changed so that it works?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the script to footer.php and it will probably work, but it's not the best way to avoid jQuery conflicts.

The best way is to enqueue the script from a separate file. See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script  which has a parameter to load scripts in footer via wp_footer .

And see The Developer’s Guide To Conflict-Free JavaScript And CSS In WordPress: http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/12/developers-guide-conflict-free-javascript-css-wordpress/

Comment: Thank you songdogtech, the links all added to my understanding, I appreciate it.  I will have to look in to js and shortcode as the js is not reading the ont put of my shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a 'little' late, but just in case anybody is still looking:

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/run-javascript-only-after-entire-page-has-loaded/

Nice and simple way of doing it!